# What is known about products of zeta values?

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

A couple of years ago, I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751929/can-the-exact-value-of-the-product-over-the-riemann-zeta-function-at-even-argume) MSE question on the evaluation of the product of even zeta values: $$ \prod_{n=1}^\infty \zeta(2n) \approx 1.82 \quad .$$ While it can be shown that the product converges, the exact value is -- as far as I know -- unknown (please correct me if this isn't the case).

I wonder to what extent more general products of (Riemann) zeta values, e.g.

$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n} \zeta(c_{n} \cdot n), $$ for some sequences $(a_{n})$ and $(c_{n})$ have been studied, and what kind of results have been obtained. Even though a thing or two is known about rational zeta [series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_zeta_series), information on their product counterparts seems to be sparse. Any pointers to relevant literature are much appreciated.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A080729](https://oeis.org/A080729) and Kellner's paper referenced there.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you.